# How do I add a IBAction to a button programmatically in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

How do I add a IBAction to a button programmatically?

```
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonAction:")), for: 
.touchUpInside)

func buttonAction(sender: Any) {
    print("test")
}
```

That gives me an "**Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**" error.

Comment: "You deleted an Outlet/Action connection in code or renamed it (spelling mistake?)." - is **not** the case :')

Comment: btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testFunction(_:)), for: .touchDown) swift 3.2

Comment: Technically, you don't "add" an `IBAction` programmatically - the "IB" stands for "Interface Builder". What you mean to ask is how use the `sender` in an `addTarget(action:)` call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Swift 4 version:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc private func action(sender: Button) {
    print("test")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yea I've seen this code before. But Swift yells at me with:                                                                                               
_"Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'buttonAction(sender:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C Add '@objc' to expose this instance method to Objective-C"_

Comment: that's why there is the `@objc` annotation

Comment: @Mofawaw then add "@objc", should look like "@objc func buttonAction()"

Comment: `@objc func action(sender: Button)`

Comment: Ofc, I just want to see if it works in the simulator:)

Comment: I had to wait 2 minutes, not my programming. :')