# UIButton press not working with an IF statement

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipickerview

I am currently trying to get an `if` statement working only when the user presses on the UIButton which will then run the `self.eslTopics.isHidden = false` in order to show my UIPickerView. What is the correct syntax of writing the `if` statement? I currently have a button called "showwheel" which is meant to change the pickerview UI from hidden = true to false.

```
if showWheel{
    self.eslTopics.isHidden = false
}
```

Xcode is trying to throw an error:

> Optional type 'UIButton!' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead, Replace 'showWheel' with '(showWheel != nil)'

which also doesn't make sense or work.

Comment: please provide button's action method code.

Comment: ask clearly better check out how to ask qtn

Comment: You should read Apple's documentation for `UIButton`, `UIControl` and `target/action`

Comment: do some research before asking anything

Comment: showWheel is a button, cannot be used as boolean in if condition. You would require a boolean variable to make this if condition work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `IBAction` method and connect to `TouchDown` event of a `UIButton`.

```
@IBAction func btnShowWheelTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

     self.eslTopics.isHidden = false
}
```

*NOTE: If you implement button's default touchup inside event then it will be called when touched is lifted from button.*

For Reference...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to associate an `IBAction` with the button press and add the code in that method.

```
@IBAction func toggleVisibility(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.eslTopics.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your variable `showWheel` is an instance variable of type `UIButton!` (implicitly unwrapped optional `UIButton`) then your code is not legal.

In C/C++/Objective-C, it's legal to say

```
if showWheel
```

And the compiler takes that to mean  "if showWheel is true", and true is equivalent to `!0` / `!nil`.

That is not legal in Swift. In Swift, you must explicitly check for nil for optionals, so your code would need to read

```
if showWheel != nil
```

Note that you should **NOT** put your conditional inside parentheses in Swift. Do not use `if (showWheel != nil)` like you would in C/C++/Objective-C/Java.

Answer (score -1):

As the error mentions:

> Optional type 'UIButton!' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!=
>   nil' instead, Replace 'showWheel' with '(showWheel != nil)'

`showWheel` is type of UIButton, means that if you are typing:

```
if showWheel { }
```

it means that it is check if `showWheel` is *nil*, it is the same as:

```
if showWheel != nil { }
```

which seems to be unrelated to what are you asking for, we already assume that `showWheel` is not nil.

What you should do -in the `IBAction` of `showWheel`- is to call `self.eslTopics.isHidden = false` directly without any if statement.

*If you are not familiar with adding an action to a UIButton, you could check*:

- [How do I add a IBAction to a button programmatically in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949969/how-do-i-add-a-ibaction-to-a-button-programmatically-in-swift-4) (programmatically).
- [Mahendra GP's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50968353/5501940) answer (via Storyboard).